# how can i split data from column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, select, time-series

i have data frame like belows

> ```
> Date       Time           
> 2017-12-01 00:00:00  21.64
>            00:15:00  21.72
>            00:30:00  21.57
>            00:45:00  21.47
>            01:00:00  21.42
>            01:15:00  21.44
>            01:30:00  21.48
>            01:45:00  21.32
>            02:00:00  21.27
>            02:15:00  21.29
>            02:30:00  21.20
>            02:45:00  21.18
>            03:00:00  21.19  
> 2017-12-02 00:00:00  22.78
>            00:15:00  22.67
>            00:30:00  22.54
>            00:45:00  22.55
> ```

i wanna split everyday data df1 is 00:00:00 and 
df2 is 00:15:00~03:00:00

how can i do it?

Comment: What return `print(df.index.get_level_values(1))` ?

Comment: Index([00:00:00, 00:15:00, 00:30:00, 00:45:00, 01:00:00, 01:15:00, 01:30:00,
       01:45:00, 02:00:00, 02:15:00,
       ...
       03:45:00, 04:00:00, 04:15:00, 04:30:00, 04:45:00, 05:00:00, 05:15:00,
       05:30:00, 05:45:00, 06:00:00],
      dtype='object', name='Time', length=1350)

Comment: Thank you, and `print(type(df.index.get_level_values(1)[0]))` ?

Comment: <class 'datetime.time'>

Comment: i have tried your answer but "got Empty DataFrame" for mask 00:00:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need if second level is filled by `string`s use [`slicers`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx[:, '00:00:00'],:]
print (df1)
                       col
Date       Time           
2017-12-01 00:00:00  21.64
2017-12-02 00:00:00  22.78

df2 = df.loc[idx[:, '00:15:00':'03:00:00'], :]
print (df2)
                       col
Date       Time           
2017-12-01 00:15:00  21.72
           00:30:00  21.57
           00:45:00  21.47
           01:00:00  21.42
           01:15:00  21.44
           01:30:00  21.48
           01:45:00  21.32
           02:00:00  21.27
           02:15:00  21.29
           02:30:00  21.20
           02:45:00  21.18
           03:00:00  21.19
2017-12-02 00:15:00  22.67
           00:30:00  22.54
           00:45:00  22.55
```

Another solution is filter by mask:

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values(1) =='00:00:00'
df1 = df[mask]
print (df1)
                       col
Date       Time           
2017-12-01 00:00:00  21.64
2017-12-02 00:00:00  22.78

df2 = df[~mask]
```

---

If second level are python times chane value for comparing:

```
import datetime

idx = pd.IndexSlice
df1 = df.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 0)],:]
print (df1)
                       col
2017-12-01 00:00:00  21.64
2017-12-02 00:00:00  22.78

df2 = df.loc[idx[:, datetime.time(0, 15, 0):datetime.time(3, 0, 0)], :]
print (df2)
                       col
2017-12-01 00:15:00  21.72
           00:30:00  21.57
           00:45:00  21.47
           01:00:00  21.42
           01:15:00  21.44
           01:30:00  21.48
           01:45:00  21.32
           02:00:00  21.27
           02:15:00  21.29
           02:30:00  21.20
           02:45:00  21.18
           03:00:00  21.19
2017-12-02 00:15:00  22.67
           00:30:00  22.54
           00:45:00  22.55
```

---

```
mask = df.index.get_level_values(1) == datetime.time(0, 0)
df1 = df[mask]

df2 = df[~mask]
```